# how to draggable over one div to another div using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to do small game like match the following using drag and drop using jquery.First i tried to move the droggable element to dropped place(Div) using below code,

**CSS**

```
#wrapper {
    width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: hidden; /* will contain if #first is longer than #second */
}
#first {
    width: 250px;
    float:left; /* add this */
    border: 1px solid red;
}
#second {
    border: 1px solid green;
    overflow: hidden; /* if you don't want #second to wrap below #first */
}
```

**Index.jsp**

```
<div align="center">
<div align="center" id="wrapper">
<div id="Questions">

<label id="Q1">Cat</label><br><br>
<label id="Q2">Cow</label><br><br>
<label id="Q3">Eagle</label><br><br>
</div>

<div id="Answers">

<label id="A1">Milk</label><br><br>
<label id="A2">Snake</label><br><br>
<label id="A3">Rat</label><br><br>
</div>

</div>
</div>



 <script type="text/javascript">


     $(function(){



$("#A1").draggable({
    revert: "invalid",
    snap: "#Questions"
    stack: "#A1",

    drop: function( event, ui ) {

         //here want to get draggable's id and droped element's id.
         // if(ui.draggable' id =='Q1' && DropedElemnts's id =='A1'){ alert("Matched") }

      }
});
$("#A2").draggable({
    revert: "invalid"
    snap: "#Questions"
    stack: "#A2"
});
$("#A3").draggable({
    revert: "invalid"
    snap: "#Questions"
    stack: "#A3"
});


});




</script>
```

When i drag Answer div's element over Question div, its disappearing. How to fix this?

What I am trying is ,if i drag **Rat** and dropped on **Cat** means its should say matched.

How to get Dragging elements id value and on dropped elements id value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/39khs/1003/

```
$(".draggable").draggable({ cursor: "crosshair", revert: "invalid"});
 $("#A3").droppable({ accept: ".draggable", 
       drop: function(event, ui) {
           var draggable = ui.draggable;
           if($( this ).text() == "Rat" && draggable.text() == "Cat" ){
           alert("Matched");
           }
                console.log($( this ).text() +"----" +draggable.text());
               $(this).removeClass("border").removeClass("over");
         var dropped = ui.draggable;
        var droppedOn = $(this);
        $(dropped).detach().css({top: 0,left: 0}).appendTo(droppedOn);      
            }, 
      over: function(event, elem) {
              $(this).addClass("over");
               console.log(this.id);
      }
            ,
              out: function(event, elem) {
                $(this).removeClass("over");
              }
                 });
 $("#drop").sortable();

 $("#origin").droppable({ accept: ".draggable", drop: function(event, ui) {
                console.log("drop");
               $(this).removeClass("border").removeClass("over");
         var dropped = ui.draggable;
        var droppedOn = $(this);
        $(dropped).detach().css({top: 0,left: 0}).appendTo(droppedOn);      


            }});
```

Hope this will help you.